# How to find screen resolution of clients

Tags: analytics, screen-resolution

The StackOverflow analytics [post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/stack-overflow-2010-analytics/) shows an interesting metric about users' screen resolution. How is this collected? Is this something you can do with JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example:

http://www.pageresource.com/jscript/jscreen.htm

Answer (score 1):

Yes this information can be obtained with Javascript.
There values can be accessed with these variables:

Screen width: *screen.width*

Screen height: *screen.height*